# How to sort divs by two different parameters by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following content in my page which is coming from database dynamically.
My div structure is like this:

```
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="19" data-status="certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="15" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="8" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="5" data-status="certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="14" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="9" data-status="certified"></div>
```

I would like it to sort in this way firstly I will get all "certified" data-status divs to show and then all "un_certified"  to show but in that also I would like it to sort by "data-quote" numbers in increasing order.The resultant divs will show like this:

```
// first the certified quotes sorted with "data-quote"
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="5" data-status="certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="9" data-status="certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="19" data-status="certified"></div>
// uncertified quotes sorted with "data-quote"
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="8" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="14" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="15" data-status="un_certified"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the code to snippet,and I add `orderByThenBy` to abstract sort logic,also I remain the old code before

```js
var $divs = $('div.status_quotes');
var orderByThenBy = [
    { "attr": 'data-status', 'typeFunc': null },
    { "attr": 'data-quote', 'typeFunc':function (v) { return parseInt(v); } }
];
$divs.sort(function (x, y) {
    for (var i = 0; i < orderByThenBy.length; i++) {
        var vx = $(x).attr(orderByThenBy[i].attr);
        var vy = $(y).attr(orderByThenBy[i].attr);
        var typeFunc = orderByThenBy[i].typeFunc;
        if (typeFunc != null) {
            vx = typeFunc(vx);
            vy = typeFunc(vy);
        }
        if (vx !== vy) {
            return vx > vy ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
//$divs.sort(function (x, y) {
//    var statusX = $(x).attr("data-status");
//    var statusY = $(y).attr("data-status");
//    if (statusX == statusY) {
//        var quoteX = parseInt($(x).attr("data-quote"));
//        var quoteY = parseInt($(y).attr("data-quote"));
//        return quoteX > quoteY ? 1 : -1;
//    }
//    else {
//        return statusX > statusY ? 1 : -1;
//    }
//});
$divs.each(function (i, n) {
    console.info(n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="19" data-status="certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="15" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="8" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="5" data-status="certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="14" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="9" data-status="certified"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

1. sorting the divs by number.
2. splitting the divs in 2 lists (certified and un_certified)
3. returning a list, beginning with the certified list, ending with the un_certified list.

```js
var divs = $('div');
var sorted_by_number = divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).attr("data-quote") - $(b).attr("data-quote")
});
var finally_sorted = (function () {
    var certified = sorted_by_number.filter(function (index, item) {
        return $(item).attr("data-status") == "certified"
    });
    var uncertified = sorted_by_number.not(certified);
    return $.merge(certified,uncertified);
})();

finally_sorted.each(function(i,el){
  var e = $(el)
  console.log(e.attr("data-status"),e.attr("data-quote"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="19" data-status="certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="15" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="8" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="5" data-status="certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="14" data-status="un_certified"></div>
<div class="status_quotes" data-quote="9" data-status="certified"></div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Los36L5b/)